# How to find the processes using a particular Interface in Linux?

Tags: linux-networking

I want to know what are the processes using a particular interface eth0. I have already tried with netstat and lsof commands but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Identify what the IP address of eth0, then use:

`netstat -plant | grep <ip-address-of-eth0> | grep -v -`

The processes are on the last column.